# Variable Types in Vim Functions

Tags: vim, keymapping

I want to conveniently remove an accidentally placed tab while using vim. The solution that jumped out to me is making an insert-mode mapping to the following vim function:

```
function DeleteTab()
  redir => l:numSpaces "captures output of set
  set tabstop?
  redir END
  "Strip off non-numerical output of 'set tabstop?' 
  let l:numSpaces = substitute(l:numSpaces, "tabstop=", "", "") 
  let l:numSpaces = substitute(l:numSpaces, " ", "", "g")
    "all echom lines are for debugging purposes
  echom "1" 
  if l:numSpaces > 0
     echom "2"
  while 1:numSpaces > 0
     execute "normal i<bs>"
     let l:numSpaces = l:numSpaces - 1
  endwhile
endfunction
```

In addition to not doing what I intended, the result of calling this function is "1" in my messages, but not "2". This means that l:numSpaces is not being interpreted as a number. How do I do the equivalent of casting in vimscript. Also, am I missing a more easy approach?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing the redir just use `&tabstop` the ampersand gets the value and places it in the variable.

```
let l:numSpaces = &tabstop
```

The next problem you have is with this line

```
while 1:numSpaces > 0
```

You wrote a `1` (one) instead of `l` (lowercase L)

So the fixed function looks something like this.

```
function! DeleteTab()
    let l:numSpaces = &tabstop
    echom "1" 
    if l:numSpaces > 0
        echom "2"
    endif
    while l:numSpaces > 0
        execute "normal i<bs>"
        let l:numSpaces = l:numSpaces - 1
    endwhile
endfunction
```

---

Also this function is kinda pointless. I believe the behavior you want should be achieved if you set the following (or to what ever value you want)

```
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
```

Hitting the backspace key should go back a full tab if you insert an accidental tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the value of an option in vimscript, you can use the syntax `&option` (see `:help expr-option`).  That simplifies the first half of your function to

```
let numSpaces = &tabstop
```

As far as undoing an accidental tab, all that should require is pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, unless you aren't inserting tab characters.

If you mean you want to "remove a level of indentation" instead of "remove a tab", then you should use the builtin command for that, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> in insert mode.  Similarly, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to add a level of indentation to the current line.  Both of these work regardless of where your cursor is in the current line, unlike trying to manage the indentation manually with <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, as well as doing the Right Thing based on your `'shiftwidth'`, `'expandtab'`, and `'tabstop'` settings.